# JPA/Hibernate repository get Custom SQL Type

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Does JPA or hibernate support custom SQL Type?
By custom SQL Type i talk about type like that :

```
CREATE TYPE [ schema_name. ] type_name
{
      FROM base_type
      [ ( precision [ , scale ] ) ]
      [ NULL | NOT NULL ]
    | EXTERNAL NAME assembly_name [ .class_name ]
    | AS TABLE ( { <column_definition> | <computed_column_definition> [ , ...n ]
      [ <table_constraint> ] [ , ...n ]
      [ <table_index> ] [ , ...n ] } )
} [ ; ]
```

This type is the result of an sql function.

If yes what is the best way to get data from the database ?
Can i use JPA projections ?
I know that i can use the Tuple or Object[] with the entityManager but i would like to use JPA and @procedure annotation
Thanks